# Missing abstract with amsart class

Tags: abstract, amsart

I'm not very good at LaTeX but I've been using it to write my dissertation. Have just come to the end and trying to format everything correctly. Whenever I try to put my Abstract paragraph into the form `\begin{abstract}` (writing here) `\end{abstract}` and click play the whole abstract section just disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
(my abstract here)
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `amsart` class does some Mysterious Stuff with abstracts: it stores the abstract in a box to be used in the title page.  To get it to appear, issue the magic command `\maketitle` *after* the abstract.

(It will then complain about a missing `\title` ... )

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}


\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
(my abstract here)
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: Missing abstract found]

Comment: The abstract will also show up if you give `\maketitle` first, although the spacing is different in the two cases.

Comment: @JosephWright as you will *also* get the error `Abstract should precede \maketitle in AMS document classes` I figured that although that worked, it shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: I just tried this (both before and after) and it wouldn't let me typeset it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Not an error: LaTeX does not stop. Must be a warning :-)

Comment: @5834578943 "wouldn't let me typeset it" is a little .. imprecise.  Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

With amsart you need a `\maketitle` to see the abstract:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\title{abc}
\author{author}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
(my abstract here)
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this affect footnotes in the abstract?  Those I have in the abstract disappear.  Those in the main body of the doc are OK.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim: Imho it is wanted that footnotes don't work, but it looks like a bug that the footnote mark appears anyway. If you need a footnote you can try `\footnotemark` in the abstract, and `\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{blub}` after \maketitle.